# Speed up regex replace

Tags: r, regex, regexp-replace

I am have a large dataframe, where I need to clean a string column. A colleague wrote a function that contains dozens and dozens of such statements:

```
  word <- gsub("#","",word)
  ...
  word <- gsub("&","",word)
```

Other than that there is hardly any code other than:

```
  word <- str_replace_all(word, "[[:punct:]]", "")
  word <- str_replace_all(word, "[^[:alnum:]]", "") 

  idx = rep(remove_numbers,length(word)) & grepl("\\D", word)
  word[idx] <- gsub("^\\d+|\\d+$", "", word[idx])
```

The function takes very long to complete. **I am looking for ways to speed this up**. My ideas:

1. Is there a way to group multiple such `gsubs` into one? I.e., a regexp like `gsub("#|&", "", word)`
2. Parallelize the application of the function

Comment: What’s `remove_numbers`? Is it a single logical value?

Comment: Mabe PCRE is faster than TRE. Setting `perl=TRUE` will switch from TRE to PCRE: `gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", "", word, perl=TRUE)`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you *can* combine the regular expressions as in your example, and yes, this should speed up the function considerably.

Instead of writing `#|…|&` you can also use character classes, and write `[#…&]`, if all the replacements concern single symbols.

Furthermore, it’s unclear why your colleague suddenly switched from `gsub` to `str_replace_all`. The two do the same thing, so you can merge those statements, too.

But, more importantly, **that last `str_replace_all` replacement makes all the others redundant**, because it removes all non-alphanumeric characters. So everything before that, which removed individual non-alphanumeric characters, is unnecessary. Just remove it.